# Sitecore 8.1 - Run without MongoDB

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I read that sitecore 8.1 has option to run CMS only mode (i.e. without xDB).

However I've not found any documentation on below:

1. Do we also need to disable aggregation task/service?
2. Any other steps we need to take?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The official documentation of Sitecore for CMS Only Mode can be found here:    [The CMS-only mode configuration settings](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/experience_management_an_overview) As for the settings you need to set:

- Xdb.Enabled
- Xdb.Tracking.Enabled
- Xdb.Configuration.XdbSettings

Also, according to the documentation, if you don't have a valid xDB license, you will run in CMS Only Mode by default.

Comment: In addition to this, https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/xdb_overview/cmsonly_mode_an_overview gives a nice overview of what you can and can't do in CMS-only mode.

Comment: Those documents seem to have vanished from the documentation site. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/experience_management_an_overview seems to be the new location.